# Show PromptChoice options as columns

Tags: c#, botframework

[image: Have this]

How can to show these two options (or more) as columns ?

I'm using:

```
var dialog = new PromptDialog.PromptChoice<string>
(new string[] { "Yes", "No" }, "Are you sure?", "Sorry, that wans't a valid option", 2);
```

The result I would like to get is:

> Are you sure ?
>
> Yes
>
> No

Comment: In which channel?

Comment: Facebook. Btw : Is it a good idea to show multiple options with prompt dialog, or you have a better solution?

Comment: For Yes/No, I would use PromptConfirm instead of PromptChoice.

Comment: Nope. I want to implement more options.

Comment: It's fine then to use PromptChoice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to change the layout of the buttons.